# docx4j replace variable with html

Tags: java, xhtml, docx4j

i got this sample code to replace variables with text and it works perfect.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File("c:/template.docx"));

VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);

MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();            

HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
mappings.put("firstname", "Name"); //${firstname}
mappings.put("lastname", "Name"); //${lastname}

documentPart.variableReplace(mappings);

wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("c:/replace.docx"));
```

but now i have to replace the variables with html. I tried something like this. but of cause it does not work

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File("c:/template.docx"));

VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);

MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();    

String html = "<html><head><title>Import me</title></head><body><p style='color:#ff0000;'>Hello World!</p></body></html>"; 

AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw.html"));
afiPart.setBinaryData(html.toString().getBytes());
afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
Relationship altChunkRel = documentPart.addTargetPart(afiPart);
CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId());


HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
mappings.put("firstname", ac.toString()); //${firstname}
mappings.put("lastname", "Name"); //${lastname}

documentPart.variableReplace(mappings);

wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("c:/replace.docx"));
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The variable replacement stuff is all about swapping out simple values in WordML, it won't work for HTML.

You need to import (X)HTML into your Word document the correct way. In the latest version of docx4j, this is done via the ImportXHTML sub-project: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML (in earlier versions, the XHTML import code is part of the main docx4j project).

Essentially the code takes well-formed XHTML, parses it into WordML constructs (i.e. text elements, runs, paragraphs and so on), and then you can insert the resulting collection of objects into your Word file. An example:

```
// Where xhtml = String representing well-formed XHTML to insert
// Where pkg = your WordProcessingMLPackage instance
XHTMLImporterImpl importer = new XHTMLImporterImpl(pkg);
pkg.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(importer.convert(xhtml, null));
```

Comment: Thanks. i also tried this and it works. But the main question is how to replace a variable with the xhtml content instead of just place to xhtml content at the end of an existing docx. There is nothing i could to?

Comment: You can use content control data binding to bind a content control via XPath to an XML element containing escaped XHTML.  Or you could convert the XHTML to WordML as Ben describes, then use that WordML in your VariableReplace mappings.  Provided the content is valid in the location in which it is being inserted (eg a sibling of w:p, as opposed to inside a w:t), that ought to work. Note that to place your variables this way, you'd have to edit the XML, not use Word!

Comment: Hi Pixel, Can you tell me what are the jars you included in classpath. I am getting exception relate to jars.

Comment: Hi Amkit i use commons-io-2.4.jar, docx4j-3.1.0.jar, docx4j-ImportXHTML-3.0.1.jar, itext-2.1.7.jar, jaxb-xmldsig-core-1.0.0.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar, xhtmlrenderer-3.0.0.jar

Comment: @JasonPlutext, would you mind expanding on the comment provided? `XHTMLImporterImpl` returns a list of paragraph objects, and obviously it cannot be inserted into an existing `w:p`. so am I correct in saying the existing position needs to be retrieved and the new content inserted there?

Comment: @epoch That's correct: you should be able to get the index of the `p` object that you're replacing, and you can then insert the generated collection at that position.

Comment: @BenPoole, thanks ben, would you mind if I show you my code to see if you can identify any problems? it runs fine :) i'm just being cautious, it is located here: https://gist.github.com/epochcoder/478a72a4b59a43995373#

Comment: @epoch Looks OK to me assuming that each matching `p` element *only* contains the relevant identifier text?

Comment: @BenPoole, it does yes :), thank you so much for looking at it!